# Unable to skip the duplicates while transform the xml through xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

When I'm trying to parse the XML file by applying the XSLT, unable to skip the duplicate values while getting the distinct values.

This is the XML file having raw values and columns which shows the data in XML format

```
<Poll>
<SQLConnection>
<SQLCommand identifier="TIMEPUNCH">
    <Data>
        <Row sdt="12-03-2017 00:00:00" edt="12-03-2017 00:00:00" e="7" j="630" Expr1004="630" cin="11:07a" cout="1:24p" hrs_ovrday="0" hrs_ovrwk="2.6333" tips="23" sales=256" hrs_holida="0" rh="4.1833" total_pay="113.87"/>
        <Row sdt="12-03-2017 00:00:00" edt="12-03-2017 00:00:00" e="7" j="630" Expr1004="630" cin="6:04a" cout="10:36a" hrs_ovrday="0" hrs_ovrwk="2.6333" tips="0" sales="0" hrs_holida="0" rh="4.1833" total_pay="113.87"/>
        <Row sdt="12-03-2017 00:00:00" edt="12-03-2017 00:00:00" e="71" j="400" Expr1004="400" cin="12:05p" cout="3:18p" hrs_ovrday="0" hrs_ovrwk="0" tips="47.59" sales="357.61" hrs_holida="0" rh="7.5" total_pay="78.75"/>
        <Row sdt="12-03-2017 00:00:00" edt="12-03-2017 00:00:00" e="71" j="500" Expr1004="500" cin="4:07p" cout="8:24p" hrs_ovrday="0" hrs_ovrwk="0" tips="47.59" sales="357.61" hrs_holida="0" rh="7.5" total_pay="78.75"/>
    </Data>
</SQLCommand>
</SQLConnection>
</Poll>
```

By using this XSLT over this I'm not able to transform the above XML to meaningful data

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="include-control-elements">true</xsl:param>
    <xsl:key name="RECORDS" match="/Poll/SQLConnection/SQLCommand/Data/Row" use="../../@identifier"/>
    <xsl:key name="TIMEPUNCH" match="/Poll/SQLConnection/SQLCommand[@identifier='TIMEPUNCH']/Data/Row" use="@j"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:if test="not($include-control-elements = 'false')">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="HEADER"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Location | Environment[*] | Diagnostics"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="LaborGroup"/>
            </xsl:if>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="LaborGroup">
        <xsl:variable name="timepunch" select="key('RECORDS','TIMEPUNCH')"/>
        <xsl:if test="$timepunch">
            <Labor>
                <xsl:if test="$timepunch">
                    <TM0 type="SHIFT">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$timepunch" mode="TIMEPUNCH"/>
                    </TM0>
                </xsl:if>
            </Labor>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Row" mode="TIMEPUNCH">
        <TM1>
            <xsl:attribute name="e"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@e,'0000')"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@j|@tips|@sales|@rh" mode="String"/>
            <xsl:variable name="varOvrTimeHr" select="@hrs_ovrday+@hrs_ovrwk+@hrs_holida"/>
            <xsl:variable name="varRegHour" select="concat(substring-before(format-number( (@rh ),'0.00'),'.'),':', format-number((@rh * 60)mod 60,'00'))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="tempVarIn">
                <xsl:if test="count(@e)  &gt; 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$e"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(substring-before(@cin,':'),'00'),':',substring-after(@cin,':'))"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="VarIn">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="substring(substring-after(current()/@cin,':'),3,1)='a'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(@sdt,' '),' ', substring-before($tempVarIn,'a'),':00',' ','AM')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(@sdt,' '),' ',substring-before($tempVarIn,'p'),':00',' ','PM')"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="tempVarOut">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(substring-before(@cout,':'),'00'),':',substring-after(@cout,':'))"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="VarOut">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="substring(substring-after(current()/@cout,':'),3,1)='a'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(@edt,' '),' ',substring-before($tempVarOut,'a'),':00',' ','AM')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(@edt,' '),' ',substring-before($tempVarOut,'p'),':00',' ','PM')"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:attribute name="pay"><xsl:value-of select="@total_pay"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="in"><xsl:value-of select="$VarIn"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="out"><xsl:value-of select="$VarOut"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="pay"><xsl:value-of select="@total_pay"/></xsl:attribute>
        </TM1>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Row" mode="TM1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@e" mode="EMPLOYEE_ID"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@j | @r | @rh | @rp | @otr | @ot | @op | @wkh | @pay" mode="Number"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="String">
        <xsl:param name="name" select="name(.)"/>
        <xsl:param name="value" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$value">
            <xsl:attribute name="{$name}"><xsl:value-of select="$value"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is

```
<Poll>
    <Labor>
        <TM0 type="SHIFT">
            <TM1 e="0007" j="630" tips="23" sales="256" rh="4.1833" in="12-03-2017 11:07:00 AM" out="12-03-2017 01:24:00 PM" pay="113.87"/>
            <TM1 e="0007" j="630" tips="0" sales="0" rh="4.1833" in="12-03-2017 06:04:00 AM" out="12-03-2017 10:36:00 AM" pay="113.87"/>
            <TM1 e="0071" j="400" tips="47.59" sales="357.61" rh="7.5" in="12-03-2017 12:05:00 PM" out="12-03-2017 03:18:00 PM" pay="78.75"/>
            <TM1 e="0071" j="500" tips="47.59" sales="357.61" rh="7.5" in="12-03-2017 04:07:00 PM" out="12-03-2017 08:24:00 PM" pay="78.75"/>
        </TM0>
    </Labor>
</Poll>
```

Now i Just want the output like this by modifying the XSLT but unable to get the desired result

```
<Poll>
    <Labor>
        <TM0 type="SHIFT">
        <TM1 e="0007" j="630" tips="23" sales="256" in="12-03-2017 11:07:00 AM" out="12-03-2017 01:24:00 PM"/>
        <TM1 e="0007" j="630" tips="0" sales="0" in="12-03-2017 06:04:00 AM" out="12-03-2017 10:36:00 AM" />
        <TM1 e="0071" j="500" tips="47.59" sales="357.61" in="12-03-2017 04:07:00 PM" out="12-03-2017 08:24:00 PM"/>
        <TM1 e="0071" j="400" tips="0" sales="0" in="12-03-2017 12:05:00 PM" out="12-03-2017 03:18:00 PM" />
        </TM0>
    </Labor>
</Poll>
```

Explationation of the Desired Output

The Logic behind this if the "e" and "j" is same then the top row carry every attribute but the second record only contains the "in" and "out" timings else attributes show "0"(zero) in the record
 Like:
The first record is complete it has "e","j","tips","sales","in","out" all the attributes:

```
 <TM1 e="0007" j="630" tips="23" sales="256" in="12-03-2017 11:07:00 AM" out="12-03-2017 01:24:00 PM"/>
```

But the second record of the same e="0007" has values only for "e","j","in","out" and 0(zero) for "tips" and "sales" like :

```
<TM1 e="0007" j="630" tips="0" sales="0" in="12-03-2017 06:04:00 AM" out="12-03-2017 10:36:00 AM" />
```

By making some changes in the XSLT it can achieve but my logic isn't works, i'M unable to do so.

Please take a look!

Thanks!

Comment: What does "skip the same" refer to? The attributes of the `Row` elements? If so, why does the second `TM1` element in the desired output have a `tips` or `sales` attribute, it seems these have the same value in the input, why are they not skipped?

Comment: The attribute of the row elements is the data set , the  duplicate record is skip if the employee code and job code is same and if the employee code is same and job code is different then only skip the duplicate rows like sales,tips and payrate  because they are same and the in and out time is different so they comes in record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XSLT that you have shared contains some additional processing for elements that are not included in the sample XML and hence instead of modifying the shared XSLT, a new XSLT has been included in the below solution to give an idea of how the desired grouping can be achieved.

You can create a composite key using `@e` and `@j` attributes of the `<Row>` element.

```
<xsl:key name="ej-key" match="Row" use="concat(@e,'|', @j)" />
```

Using this key and matching the `<Row>` with `generate-id()` function, the required grouping can be achieved.

```
<xsl:template match="Row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ej-key', concat(@e,'|',@j))[1])]">
```

Below is the XSLT. ***The XSLT does not include logic to compute the values of `@in` and `@out` attributes***. You can add that logic within the template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="ej-key" match="Row" use="concat(@e,'|', @j)" />

    <xsl:template match="Poll">
        <xsl:copy>
            <Labor>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </Labor>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <xsl:element name="TM0">
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:value-of select="'SHIFT'" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ej-key', concat(@e,'|',@j))[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="varKey" select="key('ej-key', concat(@e,'|', @j))" />
        <xsl:element name="TM1">
            <xsl:attribute name="e">
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number($varKey/@e, '0000')" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="j">
                <xsl:value-of select="$varKey/@j" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="tips">
                <xsl:value-of select="$varKey/@tips" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="sales">
                <xsl:value-of select="$varKey/@sales" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="rh">
                <xsl:value-of select="$varKey/@rh" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<Poll>
    <Labor>
        <TM0 type="SHIFT">
            <TM1 e="0007" j="630" tips="0" sales="0" rh="4.1833" />
            <TM1 e="0071" j="400" tips="47.59" sales="357.61" rh="7.5" />
            <TM1 e="0071" j="500" tips="47.59" sales="357.61" rh="7.5" />
        </TM0>
    </Labor>
</Poll>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate the efforts that you made for this.

Comment: I have edited the output by explaining the logic because I think that in my previous post I'm not able to explain the logic clearly, now everyone can understand what it is. Can you make the changes in the XSLT again to achieve the desired output?
Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: I don't think I have understood what you need in output. Currently the shared XML has all the attributes for all the `<Row>` elements. Using grouping you can eliminate duplicates based on certain criteria. The expected output again has all the rows so not sure why you need to group them. Are you changing values for some attributes if the grouping key is same? If so, please modify the input and output XML accordingly with different values to help understand better.